# OUTGOING SMTP - Google Apps

Tags: .net, smtp, sendmail, google-apps

I want to send mails through my-site by using the [Google-Apps](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=78799), for that 
I have added below this code in my web.config file.

```
<add key="SMTPServer" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
```

Code in .vb file:

```
            Dim Mail As New MailMessage
            Mail.From = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("CustomerService")
            Mail.To = txtEmailAddress.Text
            Mail.Subject = "My subject - Recap"
            Mail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html
            Mail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal
            Dim strMailbody As String = ""
            strMailbody = <html></html>
            SmtpMail.SmtpServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SmtpServer")
            Mail.Body = strMailbody
            SmtpMail.Send(Mail)
```

while send the mail, I am getting the exception like:
*The server rejected the sender address. The server response was: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. xu6sm38668916igb.7*

Can any one help me please. 
Thanks, 
Jagadi

Answer (score 0):

Google SMTP server uses TLS encryption to send messages. You must enable SSL and set the out going port to 587 for it to work properly.

Also make sure you use the correct credentials when logging into the SMTP server.